# oracle sql: How to not select select duplicate records from table

Tags: oracle, group-by, plsql, order-by, duplication

Can any help me to fix the below sql query

```
       SELECT DISTINCT ORDER_NUMBER, FLAG
FROM TABLE
```

**Below was the result**

**Order_number FLAG**

LP-13288  false

LP-13288  true

LP-13292  false

LP-13290  true

LP-13293

LP-13291   true

LP-13289   false

**Desired output**

**Order_number FLAG**

LP-13290 true

LP-13291 true

how to not select the duplicate orders and only print the order which has flag true.

Any inputs are appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use NOT IN:

```
    SELECT DISTINCT t1.ORDER_NUMBER, t1.FLAG
    FROM TABLE t1
    WHERE t1.FLAG='true' AND t1.ORDER_NUMBER NOT IN 
    (SELECT t2.ORDER_NUMBER FROM TABLE t2
    WHERE t2.FLAG='false' OR t2.FLAG IS NULL)
```

If you don't care about nulls (that is you only want to exclude order numbers that explicitly have a false flag) just remove the "OR t2.FLAG IS NULL" condition. Also this query will return orders where possibly more than one records with flag 'true' exist (as long as there are no records with flag 'false' or null)